# how to create Docker file for Grafana tool which is in my local machine? How to integrate AAD with Grafana in kubernetes cluster?

Tags: azure-devops, dockerfile, grafana, azure-aks, docker-for-windows

Need to create a docker image of grafana app which is in my local machine. i need to deploy same image in azure kubernetes. i'm able integrate AAD with my local Grafana . so, need to create a image out of it.

i'm able to deploy ready made image from docker hub and run in kubernetes cluster but unable to integrate with AAD authentication

Problem 1 : Need docker file which will create docker image of local grafana app

problem 2 : how to integrate AAD authentication with already running GRAFANA container in Kubernetes cluster

Problem 3 : we override Defaults.ini values by ENV varaibles. Can we add ENV variables from GRAFANA UI ?

need solution for either of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

followed the article  (https://github.com/PlagueHO/Workshop-AKS#prerequisite-knowledge)

this article helped me to Create a service, deployment and ConfigMap in kubernetes cluster.

to Integrate AAD just we need to add all clientid, secret, token url, Auth Url etc in Configmap (grafana.ini)
and need to restart the POD in cluster

or

download the code from (https://github.com/grafana/grafana ) and change the AAD values in ~/conf/defaults.ini

useful articles:
https://grafana.com/docs/auth/generic-oauth/